# Alter a list of strings based on the items

Tags: c#, list, list-manipulation

I have a problem with a list that I want to alter, before outputting it back to the client.

For the sake of the question I will post an example of the list and how I need to result to look, because I have looked at Intersect, Except and everything else I could think of, but didn't get the result I am looking for.

### Example List:

1, 4, 6, 8
1, 2, 6, 8
2, 4, 6, 8
3, 4, 5, 7

### Required Result:

1, 4, 6, 8 //Initial row
-, 2, -, - //Items that have not changed will show as a -
2, 4, -, -
3, -, 5, 7

I really hope I explained it well.

I would be happy to explain this further if needed.

Thanks in advance for the advice, so far I have wrecked my brain over this. ;)

What I tried is too much to type here, so here is what I have so far. Except simply won't do anything with the data because it thinks the rows are different, so they just stay the same.

```
private List<List<string>> FilterData(List<string[]> datatable)
    {
        List<string> previousRow = new List<string>();
        List<string> currentRow = new List<string>();
        List<string> rowDifferences = new List<string>();

        List<List<string>> resultingDataset = new List<List<string>>();

        foreach (var item in datatable)
        {
            if (previousRow == null)
            {
                previousRow = item.ToList();
                continue;
            }

            currentRow = item.ToList();

            rowDifferences = currentRow.Except(previousRow).ToList();
            resultingDataset.Add(rowDifferences);
        }
        return resultingDataset;
    }
```

Comment: have you tried anything? Do you have some code written?

Comment: StackOverflow is a place you can come to get help with code you've written, so you'll need to have a go first and post what you come up with to get a positive response.

Comment: Are they 4 different lists?

Comment: It is a list of Strings.

Comment: Well that's the first thing I'd fix. Each entry has multiple items, so it would be worth reflecting that in your data structure. You don't want to have to parse each element to a list and then reformat it multiple times. It seems you probably want a `List<int?[]>` or a `List<List<int?>>` using the `null` value of `int?` for "unchanged".

Comment: The reason that it is a list of strings arrays is because that is something I had to work with. I don't like to use arrays, but tried it with that before. Problem was that the first item would always stay the same as the last one because of pointers. So I changed the string arrays to Lists, to avoid that issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few things you have to change in your code;

Here is code:

```
 private List<string[]> FilterData(List<string[]> datatable)
    {
        // List is made of String Array, so need string[] variable not list
        string[] previousRow = null ;
        string[] currentRow;
        string[] rowDifferences ;

        // to store the result
        List<string[]> resultingDataset = new List<string[]>();

        foreach (var item in datatable)
        {
            if (previousRow == null)
            {
                previousRow = item;
                resultingDataset.Add(previousRow); // add first item to list
                continue;
            }

            currentRow = item; 

            // check and replace with "-" if elment exist in previous 
            rowDifferences = currentRow.Select((x, i) => currentRow[i] == previousRow[i] ? "-" : currentRow[i]).ToArray();  
            resultingDataset.Add(rowDifferences);

            // make current as previos
            previousRow = item;
        }
        return resultingDataset;
    }
```

check this [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/aDWyWG)

Comment: I knew I was close! Looks like this is closest to what I had. I will check all the different answers and see which suits me best. This so far looks like the candidate for that!

Comment: It did indeed! This is closest to the way I wanted it. No offense to the others because they also have the mutated results as I wanted them, but this code sticks to what I had. And I like that.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static List<List<string>> FilterData(List<List<string>> datatable)
{
    var result = new List<List<string>>();

    for(var rowindex = 0; rowindex < datatable.Count; rowindex++)
    {
        // Clone the string list
        var refrow = datatable[rowindex]
            .Select(item => (string)item.Clone()).ToList(); 

        result.Add(refrow);

        // First row will not get modify anyway
        if (rowindex == 0) continue;

        var row = result[rowindex];
        // previous row of result has changed to "-", so use the original row to compare
        var prevrow = datatable[rowindex - 1]; 
        for(var columnindex = 0; columnindex < row.Count; columnindex++)
        {
            if (row[columnindex] == prevrow[columnindex])
                row[columnindex] = "-";
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

[fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/RLfJ2g)

Answer (score 0):

```
public static List<List<T>> RemoveDuplicates<T>(this List<List<T>> items, T replacedValue) where T: class
{
    List<List<T>> ret = items;

    items.ForEach(m=> {
        var ind = items.IndexOf(m);

        if(ind==0)
        {
            ret.Add(items.FirstOrDefault());
        }
        else
        {
            var prevItem = items.Skip(items.IndexOf(m)-1).FirstOrDefault();

            var item = new List<T>();
            for(var a = 0; a < prevItem.Count; a++)
            {
                item.Add(prevItem[a] == m[a]? replacedValue : m[a]);
            }

            ret.Add(item);
        }
    });

    return ret;
}
```

How to use it:

```
var items = new List<List<string>>{
    new List<string>{ "1", "4", "6", "8" },
    new List<string>{ "1", "2", "6", "8" },
    new List<string>{ "2", "4", "6", "8" },
    new List<string>{ "3", "4", "5", "7" }
};

var result = items.RemoveDuplicates("-");
```

dotNetFiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/n36p64